# Android Java NullPointerException on List

Tags: java, android

on load of my main activity, I want to look up in database all records and display in list. When it gets to the function in my DatabaseHandler class getAllClients() to read all records, it crashes. I've displayed the snippets of code here and linked to entire file. Error happens at

```
List<Client> addableClients = dbHandler.getAllClients();
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
...

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    clientListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    //Below is the code to go to the QR Code
    //Move to main screen on button click
    //
    //Intent gotoQRCode = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Keytag.class);
    //gotoQRCode.putExtra(CLIENTID, jsonObject.optString("clientID"));

    //startActivity(gotoQRCode);

    //Below line throws NullPointerException
    List<Client> addableClients = dbHandler.getAllClients();

    int clientCount = dbHandler.getClientCount();

    for(int i = 0; i < clientCount; i++) {
        Clients.add(addableClients.get(i));
    }

    populateList();
}
```

See full file at http://pastebin.com/JhYZ35ri

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public List<Client> getAllClients() {
    List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);


    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            clients.add(new Client(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(3)), cursor.getString(4)));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return clients;
}
```

See full file at http://pastebin.com/4CYheGpG

Comment: If you are correct in identifying the offending line, then `dbHandler` is `null`.

Comment: Where do you define and instantiate `dbHandler`?  It's not in the code shown.

Comment: dbHandler? or dbHandler.getAllClients()?

Comment: DatabaseHandler dbHandler; at top of MainActivity.java. Please see the pastebin

Comment: `dbHandler` is never instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

So calling

```
DatabaseHandler dbHandler
```

only declares dbHandler as type DatabaseHandler. It does not initiate it. I was missing the most critical line of code which completely slipped my mind.

```
dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

I could also call it as a global private variable at the top of the Class

```
private DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
```